# PLS-00306 error on procedure EMP (HR)

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor, procedure

i have problems with my code.. i dont know how solve it :( .. 
I need to make a file with UTL_FILE and the input look like this:

```
Departamento: 80 - Sales
=========10========20========30========40========50========60=========
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890

EMPID         LAST_NAME     FIRST_NAME          SALARY           COMM
145           Russel        John               14000        0,4          


Departamento: 60 - IT

=======================================================================
EMPID         LAST_NAME     FIRST_NAME          SALARY           COMM
103           Hunold        Alexander               9000         NULO

etc...
```

i work with hr schema and my procedure compile without problems:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE EMP (p_ID IN hr.employees.employee_id%TYPE) AS
EPRINT NUMBER;
EPRINTRecord employees%ROWTYPE;
v_FileHandle UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;

CURSOR c_emp IS
 SELECT * FROM employees
 WHERE employee_id = p_ID;

BEGIN
 v_FileHandle := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('ASD', 'emp.txt', 'w');
 SELECT * INTO EPRINTRecord
 FROM employees
 WHERE department_id = p_ID;

 UTL_FILE.PUTF(v_FileHandle, 'Departamento: %s\n', EPRINTRecord.department_id);
 UTL_FILE.PUT_Line(v_FileHandle,'=========10========20========30========40========50========60=========');
 UTL_FILE.PUT_Line(v_FileHandle,'1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890');
 UTL_FILE.PUTF(v_FileHandle, 'EMPID: %s\n', EPRINTRecord.employee_id, EPRINTRecord.last_name, EPRINTRecord.first_name, EPRINTRecord.salary, EPRINTRecord.commission_pct);
 UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_FileHandle);
 dbms_output.put_line('Escritura Correcta');

-- Manejo excepciones.
EXCEPTION
  WHEN UTL_FILE.INVALID_OPERATION THEN
  UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_FileHandle);
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20051, 'Error: Operacion no valida');
 WHEN UTL_FILE.INVALID_FILEHANDLE THEN
  UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_FileHandle);
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20052, 'Archivo no valido');
 WHEN UTL_FILE.READ_ERROR THEN
  UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_FileHandle);
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20053, 'Error de Lectura');
 WHEN UTL_FILE.INVALID_PATH THEN
  UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_FileHandle);
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20054, 'Directorio invalido');
 WHEN UTL_FILE.INVALID_MODE THEN
  UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_FileHandle);
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20055, 'Error: Modo invalido');
 WHEN UTL_FILE.INTERNAL_ERROR THEN
  UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_FileHandle);
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20056, 'Error interno DB');
 WHEN VALUE_ERROR THEN
  UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_FileHandle);
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20057, 'Error: Valor no valido');
 WHEN OTHERS THEN
  UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_FileHandle);
  RAISE;
END;
/
```

but when i execute..

```
 exec emp;
```

SQL*PLUS says:

"ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:

PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'EMP'
   ..."

if i exec emp(1); the file has been created but still empty.
Please help me! thanks in advance, and sorry about my english. (i dont know if its good).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you should be using the cursor you've defined instead of doing a `SELECT...INTO...`. Try rewriting your procedure as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE EMP (p_ID IN hr.employees.employee_id%TYPE) AS
  EPRINT NUMBER;
  v_FileHandle UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;

  CURSOR c_emp IS
    SELECT * FROM employees
    WHERE employee_id = p_ID;

BEGIN
  v_FileHandle := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('ASD', 'emp.txt', 'w');

  FOR ePrintRecord IN c_emp
  LOOP
    UTL_FILE.PUTF(v_FileHandle, 'Departamento: %s\n', EPRINTRecord.department_id);
    UTL_FILE.PUT_Line(v_FileHandle,
                      '=========10========20========30========40========50========60=========');
    UTL_FILE.PUT_Line(v_FileHandle,
                      '1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890');
    UTL_FILE.PUTF(v_FileHandle, 'EMPID: %s\n', EPRINTRecord.employee_id);
  END LOOP;

  UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_FileHandle);
  dbms_output.put_line('Escritura Correcta');

-- Manejo excepciones.
EXCEPTION
  WHEN UTL_FILE.INVALID_OPERATION THEN
  UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_FileHandle);
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20051, 'Error: Operacion no valida');
 WHEN UTL_FILE.INVALID_FILEHANDLE THEN
  UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_FileHandle);
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20052, 'Archivo no valido');
 WHEN UTL_FILE.READ_ERROR THEN
  UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_FileHandle);
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20053, 'Error de Lectura');
 WHEN UTL_FILE.INVALID_PATH THEN
  UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_FileHandle);
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20054, 'Directorio invalido');
 WHEN UTL_FILE.INVALID_MODE THEN
  UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_FileHandle);
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20055, 'Error: Modo invalido');
 WHEN UTL_FILE.INTERNAL_ERROR THEN
  UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_FileHandle);
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20056, 'Error interno DB');
 WHEN VALUE_ERROR THEN
  UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_FileHandle);
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20057, 'Error: Valor no valido');
 WHEN OTHERS THEN
  UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_FileHandle);
  RAISE;
END;
/
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but i still with problems, the file has been created and it's empty. I do not know why, has not written anything in the file.
Any suggestions? 

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: My only guess is that there's no data in the EMPLOYEES table for the ID you're putting in. Try removing the WHERE clause from the cursor to see if that changes the output. Best of luck.